# onclick function calls undefined in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am creating a simple task management system in laravel and ajax. I was trying to implement a function into an edit button (using onclick)  which was supposed to trigger a modal and get details of the required Id. But I am making the following error

[image]

my codes from controller :

```
public function getTasks(Request $request){
    if($request->ajax())
 {
  $output = '';
  $query = $request->get('query');
  if($query != '' && $query != 'All')
  {
   $data = Task::join('projects', 'projects.id', '=', 'tasks.project_id')
        ->where('projects.id', $query)
        ->orderBy('priority', 'ASC')
        ->paginate(10,array('tasks.*', 'projects.project_name'));
  }
  else
  {
   $data = DB::table('tasks')
     ->orderBy('priority', 'ASC')
     ->paginate(10);
  }
  $total_row = $data->count();
  if($total_row > 0)
  {
   foreach($data as $row)
   {
    $output .= '
            <div class="col-12 col-md-3 border p-4 m-4" id="get_task_id" data-id="'.$row->id.'">
                <span class="handle"></span>
                <h4>'.$row->task_name.'</h4>
                <p>#'.$row->priority.'</p>
                <p>Scheduel : '.date('d F, Y', strtotime($row->date_time)).'</p>
                <div class="row d-flex justify-content-end">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="taskEditData('.$row->id.')">
                      Edit Task
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger">X</button>
                </div>
            </div> 
           ';
   }
  }
  else
  {
   $output = '
   <tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="5">No Product Found</td>
   </tr>
   ';
  }
  $data = array(
   'table_data'  => $output,
   'total_data'  => $total_row
  );
  echo json_encode($data);
 }
}
```

And from the route :

```
Route::get('singleTask/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\Master@taskEditData');
```

And from the js file :

```
function taskEditData(id) {
$('#task').modal('show');
$.ajax({
    type: "GET"
    , DataType: 'json'
    , url: "/singleTask/" + id
    , success: function (data) {
        // console.log(data);
        $('.updateButtonShow').show();
        $('.addButtonShow').hide();

        $('#project_name').val(data.project_name);
        $('#project_id').val(data.project_id);
        $('#task_name').val(data.task_name);
        $('#date_time').val(data.date_time);
        $('#priority').val(data.priority);
       
        $('#taskId').html(data.id);
        
       }
   })
  }
```

And from the blade

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between sort_task" id="sort_task">
    
    </div>

    <div id="total_records">

    </div>

</section>

<!-- Task Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="task" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" 
aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form>
       @csrf
       <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add New Task</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label>Task Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="project_name" class="form-control">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label>Select Project</label>
            <select name="project_name" class="form-control">
                @foreach($projects as $project)
                  <option value="{{$project->id}}">{{$project->project_name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label>Scheduel</label>
            <input type="date" name="date_time" class="form-control">
         </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" id="add" class="btn btn-primary addButtonShow">Add Task</button>
            <button type="button" id="edit" class="btn btn-primary updateButtonShow">Update 
            Task</button>
          </div>
       </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To Pull in js file :

```
  fetch_customer_data();

  function fetch_customer_data(query = '')
  {
   $.ajax({
   url:"getTasks",
   method:'GET',
   data:{query:query},
   dataType:'json',
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#sort_task').html(data.table_data);
    $('#total_records').text(data.total_data);
   }
  })
 }

});
```

Comment: How are you pulling in your `.js` file?

Comment: I have added the code at the last part now , sorry for missing that part

Answer (score 1):

I may need to revise this answer, but I think the issue is that it can't find your javascript file.

For example, in your blade template you'll need something like this:

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between sort_task" id="sort_task">
    
    </div>

    <div id="total_records">

    </div>
    <script src="path-to-your-js-file.js"/>
</section>
```

Then within that `.js` file, you have your `taskEditData` method. Right now the error you're seeing is because the browser can't find the `taskEditData` method.

Or if you are using a layout file, that is where I would put my `<script>` tags.

Comment: I had the script file in app.blade , can I ask you a different issue ? how can I json_decode  $imageids = request()->input("imageids");